# Android - SQLite database to string

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i have a "small" problem, i have SQLite databse and i need to get from a table "Champions" column "displayName" all values (text) to strings, and call them by id to display in textview? I cant find that already 2 hours... Any solution? (I need to get  strings from one column, sort them by id. On load of Activity show that text value in textview, called by id.) Any good solution? Many thanks for every reply.

Sorry for bad english, and stupid question, but im new in programming (just java, im a little good in uselees Visual Basic).

EDIT: Or just eexport column to xml strings. Can I do that? Thanks

Comment: a single text view, or a list view?

Comment: some (over 80) textviews (or buttons, but that does not matte, changing text one textview or button. i am rigth?)

Answer (score 1):

use DataBaseHelper:

```
    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this.context, "animals.db");
    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Toast.makeText(context,
                context.getString(R.string.error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }
    try {
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        Toast.makeText(context,
                context.getString(R.string.error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        throw sqle;
    }
```

and cursor:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.query("animals", null, null, null, null, null, null);

    ArrayList<Animals> animals = new ArrayList<Animals>();

    int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("_id");
    int nameColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
    ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String name = c.getString(nameColIndex);
            nameList.add(name);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
```

read [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)